# How to trigger function when resizing window?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to resize `somediv` when the window is manually resized.

```
<script>

(function resizeElement() {
    let height = window.innerHeight - 90;
    somediv.style.height = height + 'px';
    $( "#target" ).html( "<div>" + $( window ).width() + " , " \
        + $( window ).height() + "</div>" );
})();

// Listen for resize changes
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeElement);

</script>
```

This does not apply the function when the screen is resized. The following works but forces me to declare the function twice.

```
<script>

(function resizeElement() {
    let height = window.innerHeight - 90;
    somediv.style.height = height + 'px';
    $( "#target" ).html( "<div>" + $( window ).width() + " , " \
        + $( window ).height() + "</div>" );
})();

// Listen for resize changes
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  let height = window.innerHeight-90;
  somediv.style.height = height+'px';
  $( "#target" ).html( "<div>" + $( window ).width() + " , " + $( window ).height() + "</div>" );
}, false);

</script>
```

Any idea how I can avoid double declaring?

EDIT: How would it work if I wanted to make `90` a variable called `somevar`.  How would I pass this?

**EDIT SOLVED**:

```
<script>

let padding_text = 90;

function resizeElement(padding_text) {
    let height = window.innerHeight - padding_text;
    somediv.style.height = height + 'px';
    $( "#target" ).html( "<div><i>w:" + $( window ).width() + " h:" + $( window ).height() + "</i></div>" );
};

// Listen for resize changes
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    resizeElement(padding_text);
}, false);

// Lets invoke it for the first time when the page loads
resizeElement(padding_text);

</script>
```

Comment: Can you add your html for a slightly more complete example for easier replication? At least the chunk containing somediv

Comment: The first one is a function expression. The function `resizeElement` literally does not exist at the moment you call `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are evaluating `resizeElement` function just as declaring it, by putting it inside the parentheses; This syntax is An [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression). IIFE is a JavaScript function that runs as soon as it is defined. scope enclosed within the Grouping Operator `()`, prevents accessing variables within the IIFE idiom as well as polluting the global scope.

This syntax makes the `resizeElement` function name unavailable for the scope out of that parentheses. Remove that immediate evaluation of that function and just add a single function call later.

```
function resizeElement() {
    let height = window.innerHeight - 90;
    somediv.style.height = height + 'px';
    $( "#target" ).html( "<div>" + $( window ).width() + " , " \
        + $( window ).height() + "</div>" );
}

// Listen for resize changes
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeElement);

// Lets invoke it for the first time when the page loads
resizeElement()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the self invoking function? Remove it and it should work.

```
<script>
function resizeElement() {
    let height = window.innerHeight - 90;
    somediv.style.height = height + 'px';
    $( "#target" ).html( "<div>" + $( window ).width() + " , "
        + $( window ).height() + "</div>" );
}
// Listen for resize changes
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeElement, false);
</script>
```

The reason it wasn't working is because you declared `resizeElement` in a scope not accessible to the event listener assignment.